# Getting an error when trying to add a key to an object with a template literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-template-literals

I am trying to add a key to an object using a template literal in TypeScript. This is being done by a function that takes a generic of the object. I keep getting the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`${string}Bar`' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
```

Here is a stripped down version of what I am trying to do:

```
type FooDatum = {
  foo: string;
  baz: string;
  fooBar?: string;
}

function addFooBar<Datum>(obj: Datum, dataKey: keyof Datum) {
  obj[`${String(dataKey)}Bar`] = obj[dataKey];

  return obj;
}

addFooBar<FooDatum>({ foo: 'bar', baz: 'string' }, 'foo')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAIgQ2AVwLZQLxQN4BQUUAZggFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gNxFQBGyAXpTQxbtiZOACFktAPz86TNgQC+BAiTSMAxsHpxGUZABMD8cZIA8KdBgB8ACjicAVpUuYANFAOpkAaQghKAGt-OBIoVwwASnwOB0cAbQADABI8AGU5FlsvYF9-SMUJWkSAXRwoOPicvJAS9g5aCHRaPTj2ZQJDYwQisxMIuzxSCigAcm5aUY9uPjGBeVGoRQ9R0VHIoA)

Comment: Not sure if [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAIgQ2AVwLZQLxQN4CwAUFFAGYIBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcxpARsgF7U6TNpxLkEAIWT1BDFh2IBfYsVCQoAeWYAbEAGkIIGgHVGwABZT6AHgAqUCAA9gEZgBMatOWwB8OKLYqRMRkaMwAxsCMcMxQyG5u8HBWdg7Orh5QAEoQ4XD0btYABgAkeHqKVkUANF7CrD61emku7p5C8j4AFHDcAFbUGhhmdrWl5ZXSRY1QbqjIBiDUegCU+FxQ9BDo9LF4UAB0R719tQDa43PAC4aT9EUAutQA5BS90s9QiqJKQfGJkmk1iSKHQGFqrwQz26+zeL149GetV4Aigzw6bE+ighb2eKyAA) will be fine for you, but we can adjust it for you requirements

Comment: @SpencerCarney can you uncover a bit more data on why

Comment: @Dimava I need to add additional values to the `obj` parameter.

Comment: @wonderflame that is very close, but I neglected a detail, which is the setting of the dynamic value to `obj[dataKey]`. I updated my code in the question above.

Comment: Does [this one](https://tsplay.dev/WGBAom) work?

Comment: okay will write the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this solution works it may not be the best one for scaling.
We must use a generic parameter for the whole object.

To ensure that adding a new property to an object will work we will define the type as an object with the initial value of the key and optional property with the key postfixed with `Bar`. The parameter for the key will have the constraint to be the string key of the object.

```
function addFooBar<T extends { [P in `${K}Bar`]?: string } & { [P in K]: string }, K extends keyof T & string>(obj: T, dataKey: K) {}
```

Unfortunately, directly setting the property with the dynamic key will lose the type of the key and going to be widened to just `string`. To prevent this we will need to have a separate function that is typed and prevents the narrowing:

```
// To ensure the dynamic key is typed correctly
function record<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): { [prop in K]: V };
function record<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key]: value };
}
```

Implementation:

```
function addFooBar<T extends { [P in `${K}Bar`]?: string } & { [P in K]: string }, K extends keyof T & string>(obj: T, dataKey: K) {
  return { ...obj, ...record(`${dataKey}Bar`, obj[dataKey]) };
}
```

Testing:

```
// FooDatum & {
//     fooBar: string;
// }
const a = addFooBar({ foo: 'bar', baz: 'string' } as FooDatum, 'foo') // no error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAIgQ2AVwLZQLxQN4CwAUFFAGYIBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcxpARsgF7U6TNpxLkEAIWT0A-IIYsOxAL7FiAenVQAKnCgRmNNPWgATEM2QZGAYygBrCCCiMaUUJFNQbceiZvAADYgxGRozAGMcMxQ-r6mADwA0voAHsAGpm5CigA0UABqAHwAFI4g1En5AG7IgWgQ1AUAlNR4UADaYPRwYC4xSQC6TVDKomERwFExcfSJKRDpmdkKbPnFZU6VNXUNTc34XLEQ6PQx7R3lw1C19dBjKmpEE5HRUMimpvBwUvQJ2mkMswsvhOgAFfpQAAGABI8EllL8oYM5LRVqxRlAAGSgjoQlhQIbyYQY5T5BZLYFucpwMg6bFokmlODcABW1G0+VMqGQSS2hIOhDEJlO5ygADpJSzWflJeLZqYSrC8NzgLynIjpFD8tKOqr1SBBgcHkRVEQNFpvih0FgcULNKRHRQftJiYpRA6zT5DMB3jh3p9vr8Su1ndQAOS8ejh-K8ARQcM5NjhzHINxW1CYfLh53hg4O5h6CB+XxAA)